# Firebase: using admin sdk to store images

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am trying to store images to firebase storage, I am using node.js.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://xxx-app.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: 'xxxx-app.appspot.com'
});


function storeHeadShots(){

    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    bucket.upload('./headshots/Acker.W.png', function(err, file){
        if (!err){
            console.log('file uploaded')
        } else {
            console.log('error uploading image: ', err)
        }
    });

}
storeHeadShots();
```

Now the above works fine, but I have a folder in storage `users/` and inside this folder I am storing images. **How do I access this folder** ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to download the files? If so you can use [`file.download()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/test/integration/storage.spec.ts#L55) method.

Comment: no man, I am looking for a way to reference the folder `users/` and inside that folder where the images reside... when doing this `const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()` it works fine but stores files/images in root level, I want to go one level deep , hence inside `users/` folder

Answer (score 12):

For anybody who was trying to solve the same problem.

The example is taken from the official documentation [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js) but it doesn't say anything about how to put a file inside a folder. The default example puts the file under the root of the bucket with the same name as the local file.

I had to dig a little deeper into the Cloud Storage class documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#upload) and I found that for the `options` a `destination` parameter exists that describes the file inside the bucket.

In the following example the local file `images/bar.png` will be uploaded to the default bucket's file `/foo/sub/bar.png`.

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

bucket.upload('images/bar.png', {
  destination: 'foo/sub/bar.png',

  gzip: true,
  metadata: {
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'
  }
}).then(() => {
  console.log('file uploaded.');
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('ERROR:', err);
});
```

Hopefully that saved some time for others. Happy uploading!

Comment: where's filename coming from

Comment: it's not needed. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for updating it I was quite confused about the filename variable

Comment: Is there a way to get the download url after upload?

Comment: @TylerRutt a little late but you should be able to reconstruct the URL from the destination concatenating to the bucket's URL.

Comment: How to upload from blob?